# Using multiple database connections inside controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I have setup multiple database connections

```
"wc" => [
            "driver" => "mysql",
            "url" => env("DATABASE_URL"),
            "host" => env("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
            "port" => env("DB_PORT", "3306"),
            "database" => env("DB_DATABASE", "forge"),
            "username" => env("DB_USERNAME", "forge"),
            "password" => env("DB_PASSWORD", ""),
            "unix_socket" => env("DB_SOCKET", ""),
            "charset" => "utf8mb4",
            "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            "prefix" => "",
            "prefix_indexes" => true,
            "strict" => true,
            "engine" => null,
            "options" => extension_loaded("pdo_mysql")
                ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env("MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA"),
                ])
                : [],
        ],

        "ys" => [
            "driver" => "mysql",
            "url" => env("DATABASE_URL"),
            "host" => env("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
            "port" => env("DB_PORT", "3306"),
            "database" => env("DB_DATABASE", "forge"),
            "username" => env("DB_USERNAME", "forge"),
            "password" => env("DB_PASSWORD", ""),
            "unix_socket" => env("DB_SOCKET", ""),
            "charset" => "utf8mb4",
            "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            "prefix" => "",
            "prefix_indexes" => true,
            "strict" => true,
            "engine" => null,
            "options" => extension_loaded("pdo_mysql")
                ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env("MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA"),
                ])
                : [],
        ],


DB_CONNECTION=wc
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=ys
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ys
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and i would like to choose which conenction to use when running a controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\adx_world;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function creator(){
       
     $data=array('name'=>time(),"city"=>time());
     DB::connection('ys')->table('test')->insert($data);
     echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    
    }
}
```

This throws an error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Connection adx_world is not in the config you provided. Could this be related?

Comment: @StewieSWS Not related. Was a typo.

Comment: Possibly a silly/obvious question, but does your `ys` MySQL instance have a `test` table? I.e. have you made sure to run the proper migrations against both connections?

Comment: Ah ha, yes, that too would do it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect. You are using same env variables for both connections, which means that you're overwriting it in .env file. So you need unique keys in env files which are used in 2 connections.

Change to this your config and env:

```
"wc" => [
        "driver" => "mysql",
        "url" => env("DATABASE_URL"),
        "host" => env("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
        "port" => env("DB_PORT", "3306"),
        "database" => env("DB_DATABASE", "forge"),
        "username" => env("DB_USERNAME", "forge"),
        "password" => env("DB_PASSWORD", ""),
        "unix_socket" => env("DB_SOCKET", ""),
        "charset" => "utf8mb4",
        "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
        "prefix" => "",
        "prefix_indexes" => true,
        "strict" => true,
        "engine" => null,
        "options" => extension_loaded("pdo_mysql")
            ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env("MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA"),
            ])
            : [],
    ],

    "ys" => [
        "driver" => "mysql",
        "url" => env("YS_DATABASE_URL"),
        "host" => env("YS_DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
        "port" => env("YS_DB_PORT", "3306"),
        "database" => env("YS_DB_DATABASE", "forge"),
        "username" => env("YS_DB_USERNAME", "forge"),
        "password" => env("YS_DB_PASSWORD", ""),
        "unix_socket" => env("DB_SOCKET", ""),
        "charset" => "utf8mb4",
        "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
        "prefix" => "",
        "prefix_indexes" => true,
        "strict" => true,
        "engine" => null,
        "options" => extension_loaded("pdo_mysql")
            ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env("MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA"),
            ])
            : [],
    ],


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

YS_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
YS_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
YS_DB_PORT=3306
YS_DB_DATABASE=ys
YS_DB_USERNAME=root
YS_DB_PASSWORD=
```